# XSL removing empty nodes within the same code

Tags: xml, svn, xslt, ant

I've created the following XSL stylesheet which takes an XML packet ( given to me from SVN ) and converts all the "entry" nodes, which don't include the text "archive", into a comma-separated list for my ANT script. An example XML file looks like this....

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lists>
   <list path="https://mydomain.com/branches">
      <entry kind="dir">
         <name>James_Work</name>
         <commit revision="2209">
            <author>James</author>
            <date>2010-09-02T11:02:08.584250Z</date>
         </commit>
      </entry>
   </list>
</lists>
```

... and my XSL is this ....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:variable name="selectionPropertyList">
      <xsl:for-each select="lists/list/entry[name!='archive']">svnType/<xsl:value-of select="name" />
         <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if> 
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
         <svnType><xsl:copy-of select="$selectionPropertyList" /></svnType>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem I'm hitting is when I get an empty packet back. This might happen for example if I call the SVN branches folder which is currently empty, and  end up with an empty entry in my ANT listing.

An example XML packet looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lists>
   <list path="https://mydomain.com/branches">
   </list>
</lists>
```

Does anyone know a way I could somehow filter out these empty packets from my listings?

Thanks,
James

P.S. I've tried the tips given here but it doesn't quite match what I'm trying to do here. 
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1088712&page=1

**Update**

Bigger example of input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<lists>
<list path="https://mydomain.com/website/branches">
<entry kind="dir">
   <name>ITNAM-752</name>
   <commit revision="2171">
       <author>jcb4337</author>
       <date>2010-08-30T15:13:21.006125Z</date>
   </commit>
</entry>
<entry kind="dir">
   <name>JCB4337-577</name>
   <commit revision="2171">
      <author>jcb4337</author>
      <date>2010-08-30T15:13:21.006125Z</date>
   </commit>
 </entry>
 <entry kind="dir">
     <name>JCB4337-726</name>
     <commit revision="2209">
        <author>jcb4337</author>
        <date>2010-09-02T11:02:08.584250Z</date>
      </commit>
  </entry>
  <entry kind="dir">
      <name>JCB4337-808</name>
      <commit revision="2206">
          <author>jcb4337</author>
          <date>2010-09-01T13:01:51.693625Z</date>
      </commit>
  </entry>
  <entry kind="dir">
        <name>JCB4337-847</name>
        <commit revision="2172">
            <author>jcb4337</author>
            <date>2010-08-30T15:14:12.803000Z</date>
         </commit>
  </entry>
 </list>
</lists>
```

The Output I'm needing to get back from the XSL is along the lines of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
 <branches>branches/ITNAM-752,branches/JCB4337-577,branches/JCB4337-726,branches/JCB4337-808,branches/JCB4337-847</branches>
</root>
```

I've used @Alejandro's code above and I'm just about there, I think. But I'm getting some strange results along the way. Output example is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <root>
      <branches>

          branches/ITNAM-752,
          branches/JCB4337-577,
          branches/JCB4337-726,
          branches/JCB4337-808,
          branches/JCB4337-847,

      </branches>
      </root>
```

So...

1) Getting a lot of white space between the list elements.

2) I've still got an extra comma at the end of the results.

3) When I try and apply this against our SVN tags folder I'm getting some odd results. Tags is slightly different because it holds this "archive" folder which I want to exclude from any results.

Currently when I output the tags folder using the same code I get this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <tags>


        archive

        jcb4337
        2010-08-31T08:56:51.006125Z


         tags/milestone 1-0-0,
         tags/milestone 1-0-0b,
         tags/milestone 1-0-1,
         tags/milestone 1-0-10,
         tags/milestone 1-0-11,
         tags/milestone 1-0-2,
         tags/milestone 1-0-3,
         tags/milestone 1-0-4,
         tags/milestone 1-0-5,
         tags/milestone 1-0-6,
         tags/milestone 1-0-7,
         tags/milestone 1-0-8,
         tags/milestone 1-0-9,

      </tags>
    </root>
```

So lots of whitespace and archive, along with all the timestamp, author information is appearing, using @Alejandro solution.

BTW, in case you're wondering I've got ANT doing a token replace straight after the XSL has finished. It's replacing the phrase svnType in the XML. I couldn't think of a way of applying the prefix branches / tags on each node using XSL.

Hope this all helps a bit more and thanks once again for everyone's efforts. XSL is a bit of a black art to me at the moment :-).

Comment: If these answers don't cover your problem, you could edit your question with remaining issues.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. I've given some more info below based on one of the solutions.

Comment: Check my update. Remember to post a comment in my answer next time. Otherwise I don't get notifications.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="list/entry[name!='archive']">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('svnType/',
                                     name,
                                     substring(',',
                                               1,
                                               position()!=last())
                                     )"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <svnType>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="lists/list/entry/name!='archive'">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:comment>There is no entry
                                     without "archive" name</xsl:comment>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </svnType>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <svnType>svnType/James_Work</svnType>
</root>
```

With this input:

```
<lists>
    <list path="https://mydomain.com/branches"></list>
</lists>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <svnType>
        <!--There is no entry with "archive" name-->
    </svnType>
</root>
```

**EDIT**: `xsl:strip-space` for stripping white space only text nodes from input source.

**EDIT**: Also, a pull style approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="entry[name!='archive']">
        <xsl:call-template name="output"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="entry[name!='archive'][last()]"
                  name="output"
                  priority="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('svnType/',name)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="lists">
        <root>
            <svnType>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </svnType>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="list[not(entry/name!='archive')]">
        <xsl:comment>There is no entry without "archive" name</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both stylesheet output:

```
<root>
   <svnType>svnType/ITNAM-752,svnType/JCB4337-577,svnType/JCB4337-726,svnType/JCB4337-808,svnType/JCB4337-847</svnType>
</root>
```

Comment: This is the one I'm trying to use at the moment. Only thing is I'm getting back this kind of thing at the moment...

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<tags>


archive

jcb4337
2010-08-31T08:56:10.756125Z


milestone 1-0-0,
milestone 1-0-1,
milestone 1-0-3,
milestone 1-0-4,
milestone 1-0-5,
milestone 1-0-6,

</tags>
</root>

Comment: So I'm getting archive, the nodes of the entry combined into one string & an extra comma at the end. It's not showing it here but I'm also getting a lot whitespace as well. Loving the comment approach though :-)

Comment: @James Buckingham: please, post your actual input, there might be diferences.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your match expression to:

```
<xsl:template match="/lists[list/entry[name != 'archive']]">
```

should work.

(I'd also use apply-templates instead of the $selectionPropertyList, but that is another issue)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:text>svnType/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="entry/name" />
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <svnType>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//list[entry/name!='archive'][*]" />
        </svnType>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

basically [*] says that the list element should have childnodes.